# Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554) in role based login in angular/ionic

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic-framework

so i get the "Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)" error in this line on the user object:

```
Storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, user);
```

this is the code of the whole method:

```
login(credentials: any): Observable<any>{
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let email = credentials.email;
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let password = credentials.password;
    let user = null;

    if (email === 'admin' && password === 'admin') {
      user = { email, role: 'ADMIN' };
    } else if (email === 'user' && password === 'user') {
      user = { email, role: 'USER' };
    } else {

    }

    this.currentUser.next(user);
    Storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, user);

    return of(user);
  }
```

any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is `Storage.set`? are you trying to do `localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, user);`?

Comment: Basically yes, with the _@capacitor/storage_

Answer (score 1):

`set()` takes an object as [seen here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage#set). The key of the object is the storage key and the value is the value of the storage value.

> set(options: SetOptions) => Promise

I am not sure if `TOKEN_KEY` is key name you want to use or a variable holding the name, so I included both ways:

```js
// If TOKEN_KEY is the name you want to use:
Storage.set({
  TOKEN_KEY: user
})

// If TOKEN_KEY is a variable holding the name:
Storage.set({
  [TOKEN_KEY]: user
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i now found a workaround with the ionic storage! The only problem is, that my user object always is Null. Would it be possible that you help me with this problem? I am sure you'd be able to help me :)